# Google Cloud Instance downtime issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Instance for 1 of my website.
But daily at same time my server went down. you can say that only 1 - 10 minutes difference daily maximum

When I checks in monitoring it shows me that Disk Throughput (Write) is very high.

I changed disk as well as using N2 Type machine

Waiting for Suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- For this scenarios usually an application running in your VM is consuming more resources than the VM has.
- You could also review if there is any peak at the same time for CPU utlization and or if there is any peak network traffic this could point to to http requests overlading your vm.
- As shot term solution you could add more persistant disk and change the machien type to increse the I/O disk performance , for reference you can review the article [Optimizing persistent disk performance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/optimizing-pd-performance#io-size)